# How can i dymically populate a list from a value in a dropdown using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown which has values. When I select a value from the dropdown, I need to look up values from the server and then dynamically populate another dropdown and display the second dropdown. 
If I select a different value from the first dropdown , I need to once again get values from a server according to that value and popup another dropdownlist with those values. I can keep selecting values from the first dropdown and popup a number of child lists. How can I do this in AngularJS ?

Comment: and what have you done so far to achieve this?

Comment: I have populated the parent dropdown, but not sure how to get the selected value and use it to bind to the child ?

Comment: mate, if you need people to help, you need to share the code as well. This helps others to get a starting point to solve your issue. SO isn't a coding service after all.

Comment: sure , will post my code so far .